# Altough I fixed the @NamedQuery, the previous error still continue, why?

Tags: jpql, jdeveloper, named-query

I have a JPQL :

```
@NamedQuery(name = "AsiErtelemeIptal.findPaketHastaAsiErtelemeIptalHastaOzlukByHastaKimlikNumarasi",
                             query = "SELECT h,p,a,ho FROM Hasta h,Paket p,AsiErtelemeIptal a,HastaOzlukBilgileri ho WHERE h.hastaKimlikNumarasi = ?1 and h.id=p.hasta.id and p.id=a.paket.id and h.id=ho.hasta.id ")
```

Error is I wrote in query `hastakimliknumarasi` instead of `hastaKimlikNumarasi`, but then I fixed it, and cleaned and rebuild class so many time. But I am still getting this error:

```
Error compiling the query [AsiErtelemeIptal.findPaketHastaAsiErtelemeIptalHastaOzlukByHastaKimlikNumarasi: 

SELECT h,p,a,ho 

FROM Hasta h,Paket p,AsiErtelemeIptal a,HastaOzlukBilgileri ho 

WHERE h.hastakimliknumarasi = ?1 and h.id=p.hasta.id and p.id=a.paket.id and h.id=ho.hasta.id ], 

line 1, column 87: unknown state or association field [hastakimliknumarasi] of class [tr.com.surat.esaglik.model.usvs.Hasta].
```

I use Jdeveloper and what is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's causing the error, but when you get errors which only have an case mismatch you should not just clean the projects involved but remove the whole classes folder.
JDev sometimes adds a additional data in the classes folder which prevents a class with only a case mismatch to compile.

Comment: yeap, I delete everything and run from scratch then it is resolved :)